# React native flatlist to know if I move to the left or to the right

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I am using `AppIntroSlider`, but I would like to implement liquid effect in pagination dots.

In order to do this, I need to understand if the shift I am making is to the left or to the right.

I tried to use `flatlist` events like: `onScrollBeginDrag` and `onScrollEndDrag`, but they are not adequate to know.

How can I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code `<FlatList onScroll={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)} ..`
it start from 0 so you can check that value and implement your logic.